# How to make it stop?! using onclick="this.firstChild.play()"

Tags: html, onclick, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a super noob making my first html mobile app for my exhibition. I want to make a simple audio tour and found this

```
jsFiddle that suits my needs perfectly
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/3UXDH/3

But I don't know how to make a stop button to work with it.

Could you please help?

Comment: What's the best course of action when the question form says you should post code along with a jsfiddle link? A) Post code along with the link, or B) highlight a random sentence with code formatting? (Hint: the answer is A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use `pause()` to stop it and remove src.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U4KqQ/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <a onclick="trombone.play()" class="button"><audio id="trombone" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg"></audio>&#9658;</a> Trombone
 <a onclick="trombone.pause()" class="button">Stop</a>
    
</div>
```

Another thing is, you don't need to use `this.firstChild`, instead you can just refer to the element by id(provide the Audio element an `id` or className so that you can refer to it easily)

[Reference Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Look at this example provided in the reference document

```
<audio id="demo" src="audio.mp3"></audio>
<div>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').play()">Play the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()">Pause the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume+=0.1">Increase Volume</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').volume-=0.1">Decrease Volume</button>
</div>
```